# What is the best way to search list of words in the pandas dataframe which is having 1 million records?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I want to search set of keywords (e.g. word = ['mobile','bags',etc]) in the pandas dataframe having approx. 1 million records.

If any of the word matches then I want to add extra column(New_col) having the value 1.

**Text**                                                                                                  **New_Col**

We are the provide of jute bags                                 1

Comment: This will automatically have O(n*m) performance, which for any sizable dataframe length (n) and word list (m) will get daunting quickly. Vectorized is the way to go though, like as follows:
`df[df['text'].str.contains("mobile|bags")]`

Comment: I tried the same, but it didn't respond for last 5-7 minutes so i killed it. I tried this on 4gb ram machine.

Comment: Welcome to the problems of computation. You can try a single query on a dataframe with 10, 100, 1000, and you can view how the **time complexity** differs with dataframe size. The issue is your query is **necessarily** long (it needs to query every element in the dataframe for every possible word, or O(n*m).

Comment: Yeah..thanks Alex :)

Comment: @Andy this is not duplicate, recheck the question statement, here problem is with the size of data not with the how to check.

Comment: @AmanTandon that's the fastest way. If you're running out of memory: chunk it up.

Comment: @Andy Out of memory is not the problem in this case, it is taking time of around 10 minutes for 1 million data. I want the more optimized way to search only such records which is having any of the set of keywords.

Comment: @AmanTandon out of memory => swap => slow. Like I say, chunks for pandas or a different more specific data structure (not a DataFrame) / database.